# Troubleshooting Kafka Topic Creation with Replication Factor Lower than Expected

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm encountering an issue with Apache Kafka where topics are being created with a replication factor lower than expected, despite having default.replication.factor=3 configured in my Kafka server properties file. I'm using Kafka version 2.5.1, and my producer is transactional with ACLs configured.

Here's a summary of my setup:

- Kafka version: 2.5.1
- Producer configuration: Transactional with ACLs configured
- Kafka server properties: default.replication.factor=3
- Issue: Topics are auto-created with a replication factor lower than 3

I've reviewed my configurations, checked Kafka logs, and tested different scenarios, but I'm still unable to resolve the issue. I suspect it could be a bug or a misconfiguration in Kafka.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this further? Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Lower than 3" meaning the default of 1? Or sometimes 2? Note: auto topic creation is not recommended to keep enabled